# How to display image tag in reactjs using template literal?

Tags: reactjs, template-literals

```
const value = weather.weather
        console.log('icon', value?.[0].icon)
        const url = `http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${value?.[0].icon}@2x.png`
        
        return(
            <div>
                <div> temperature {weather?.main?.temp} Celcius</div>
                <div>
                <img src="url" alt="icon" width="120" height="100"/>
                </div>
                <p>wind {weather?.wind?.speed} m/s</p>
            </div>
            
        )
    }
```

Why I cannot display the image behind my "url" in this case? any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to access the url variable like:

```
<img src={url} alt="icon" width="120" height="100"/>
```

Instead of "url", because it parse it literally like a string named "url", and not get the value of the variable which is the relevant url you concatenated.

Comment: True, although for some reason they stated they wanted to use a template literal, which would be `\`${url}\``

Comment: Can we see the message you get?

Comment: @JoelHager “using template literal” is a bit ambiguous here and perhaps OP meant “using a URL constructed with template literals in a component” instead of “I must use a template literal in the template”

Comment: SO is usually not the place for ambiguity, so I wanted to just clarify the verbiage.